# How can I manually specify source files that Ceedling fails to pick up?

Tags: c, unit-testing, unity-test-framework

I'm developing a feature for an embedded application and I'm using Ceedling (which builds on top of the Unity test framework) to test it. An issue that I'm having is that I need to use functionality in C source files that Ceedling isn't compiling/linking with my unit test files.

According to the Ceedling documentation:

> Ceedling knows what files to compile and link into each individual
>   test executable by way of the #include list contained in each test
>   file. Any C source files in the configured search directories that
>   correspond to the header files included in a test file will be
>   compiled and linked into the resulting test fixture executable.

The problem is that I'm including a header file "RTOS.h" in my unit tests to get access to embOS RTOS functions, but these functions are defined in "RTOSInit.c" and "os7m_tl__dp.a", and according to this documentation Ceedling will only look for "RTOS.c" when it sees `#include "RTOS.h"` in the unit test code.

What I'm looking for is a way to manually specify that these additional files should be compiled and linked when generating the test runner executable. This seems like a very basic requirement of Ceedling but I can't see a way to do this from the documentation.

I have also [raised this as an issue](https://github.com/ThrowTheSwitch/Ceedling/issues/113) on the Ceedling Github site.

For reference, my current "project.yml" file (used by Ceedling) is given below:

```
:project:
  :use_exceptions: FALSE
  :use_test_preprocessor: FALSE
  :use_auxiliary_dependencies: TRUE
  :build_root: build
  :release_build: FALSE
  :test_file_prefix: test_

:environment:
  - :path:
    - 'C:\Program Files (x86)\IAR Systems\Embedded Workbench 6.5\arm\bin'
    - 'C:\Program Files (x86)\IAR Systems\Embedded Workbench 6.5\common\bin'
    - #{ENV['PATH']}

:extension:
  :executable: .out

:paths:
  :test:
    - +:test/**
    - -:test/support
  :source:
    - src/main/c/**
    - src/main/include/**
    - src/main/resources/**
  :support:
    - test/support

:defines:
  :commmon: &common_defines []
  :test:
    - *common_defines
    - TEST
  :test_preprocess:
    - *common_defines
    - TEST

:cmock:
  :mock_prefix: mock_
  :when_no_prototypes: :warn
  :enforce_strict_ordering: TRUE
  :plugins:
    - :ignore
    - :callback
  :treat_as:
    uint8:    HEX8
    uint16:   HEX16
    uint32:   UINT32
    int8:     INT8
    bool:     UINT8

:tools:
  :test_compiler:
    :executable: iccarm
    :name: 'IAR test compiler'
    :arguments:
      - -D _DLIB_FILE_DESCRIPTOR=1
      - --debug
      - --endian=little
      - --cpu=Cortex-M3
      - -e
      - --fpu=None
      - -Ol
      - --preprocess "${3}"
      - --dlib_config "C:/Program Files (x86)/IAR Systems/Embedded Workbench 6.5/arm/INC/c/DLib_Config_Normal.h"
      - -I"$": COLLECTION_PATHS_TEST_TOOLCHAIN_INCLUDE
      - -I"$": COLLECTION_PATHS_TEST_SUPPORT_SOURCE_INCLUDE_VENDOR
      - -o "${2}"
      - --diag_suppress=Pa050
      - '"${1}"'

  :test_linker:
    :executable: ilinkarm
    :name: 'IAR test linker'
    :arguments:
      - --vfe
      - --redirect _Printf=_PrintfFull
      - --redirect _Scanf=_ScanfFull
      - --semihosting
      - --config "C:/Program Files (x86)/IAR Systems/Embedded Workbench 6.5/arm/config/generic_cortex.icf"
      - --map "${3}"
      - -o "${2}"
      - '"${1}"'

  :test_fixture:
    :executable: cspybat
    :name: 'CSpyBat test runner'
    :arguments:
      - '"C:\Program Files (x86)\IAR Systems\Embedded Workbench 6.5\arm\bin\armproc.dll"'
      - '"C:\Program Files (x86)\IAR Systems\Embedded Workbench 6.5\arm\bin\armsim2.dll"'
      - '"${1}"'
      - --plugin "C:\Program Files (x86)\IAR Systems\Embedded Workbench 6.5\arm\bin\armbat.dll"
      - --backend -B
      - --endian=little
      - --cpu=Cortex-M3
      - --fpu=None
      - --semihosting

:plugins:
  :load_paths:
    - vendor/ceedling/plugins
  :enabled:
    - stdout_pretty_tests_report
    - module_generator
...
```

Comment: Just create a symlink and it shall work

Comment: @iharob Can you clarify on what you mean by that? How can I use symlinks to make Ceedling figure to include "RTOSInit.c" and "os7m_tl__dp.a" when it sees `#include "RTOS.h"`?

Comment: Oh, you're on windows. Sorry, that will not work there.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem and used empty header files to force Ceedling compile corresponding source files. Fortunately, a new macro has been added in Unity that solves the issue. Just add something similar at the top of your test files:

```
TEST_FILE("source_file_to_compile.c")
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you specify directory that contains the file in `project.yml` sources. Ceedling won't give you any errors if it can't find specified file. Instead, it can find another file with same name but in different location (which is already specified as source)